# iPhone Google Chrome - Tab selection screen (Grouped UIViews)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-chrome, uiview

I am working on an app for iOS and I have to do a tab selection screen like the Google Chrome app for iPhone (I attached a screenshot). I searched a lot but I didn't found any similar control to use. As i can see, it groups some UIViews and use a UIScrollView to scroll, but maybe any of you could explain me better how this control works or have any solution.

Thank you!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCG5g.png

Comment: I am looking for same kind of stuff.. Can you please help us with it @Brian Sztamfater

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Different UIViews with your controls.(One tab is equal to is on UIView)
2. Add this UIView's on UIScroll View.(This is optional. It's ok if you don't use the UIScrollView and add UIView on self.view
3. Implement the touch method on UIView.
4. When you get a particular UIView is touched change it's center position to Center of the screen.
5. Which will give you the UIView which is touched in foreground and rest of the Views in background.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you .........

I solved my problem with this ......

https://github.com/xxhp/BrowserTabViewDemo

Comment: @JgdGuy This is a completely different question you are asking if you have a question then ask your own not add a comment.

Comment: @JgdGuy your comments are obsolete and I have flagged for deletion because they don't add to the value of this answer.